# function not getting called with xargs defined in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, function, expand

I added following two functions into my .bash_profile

```
function dc(){
    local command="docker container $@"
    echo $command
    eval $command
}

function dcp(){
    local params=$@
    local result=""
    for attr in $params
    do
        result=$result"{{.$attr}}\t"
    done

    local params="--format \"table $result\""

    echo "$params"
}
```

Now please find below execution after sourcing .bash_profile :-

```
~ $

dc ls
docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
bb1bb407f422        busybox             "sh"                2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                              foo
6b0bfe6d8615        busybox             "sh"                2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                              baz

~ $

dcp Image ID
--format "table {{.Image}}\t{{.ID}}\t"

~ $

dcp Image ID | xargs docker container ls
IMAGE               CONTAINER ID
busybox             bb1bb407f422
busybox             6b0bfe6d8615

~ $

dcp Image ID | xargs dc ls
dc: unrecognized option `--format'
Usage: dc [OPTION] [file ...]
  -e, --expression=EXPR    evaluate expression
  -f, --file=FILE          evaluate contents of file
  -h, --help               display this help and exit
  -V, --version            output version information and exit

Email bug reports to:  bug-dc@gnu.org .
```

Now, **xargs dc ls** is not getting coverting to **xargs docker container ls**

How can I tell xargs to expand **dc ls** call

---

**Edit 1 :-**

As suggested, I update code in **.bash_profile** as shown below :-

```
dcCall(){
    echo "params are : >$@<"
    local command=( docker images "$@" )
    echo ${command[*]}
    ${command[@]}
}

export -f dcCall
alias dc="xargs bash -c 'dcCall "$@"'"


dcp(){
    local params=$@
    local result=""
    for attr in $params
    do
        result=$result"{{.$attr}}\t"
    done

    local params="--format \"table $result\""

    echo "$params"
}
```

Now, dc is declared as an alias, so that it can be used like :-

```
dcp Repository ID | dc
```

But execution of above command gives below results :-

```
~ $

dcp Repository ID | dc
params are : ><
docker images
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
clouderassh                    latest              93f38a6c0288        34 hours ago        6.81GB
busybox                        latest              d8233ab899d4        8 days ago          1.2MB
microsoft/mssql-server-linux   2017-CU8            229d30f7b467        8 months ago        1.43GB
cloudera/quickstart            latest              4239cd2958c6        2 years ago         6.34GB
```

Now, the arguments of **dcp Repository ID** are not getting passed to
**dc**  and **params are coming empty** in **dcCall** function.

Comment: `xargs` is an external tool, so it can't use functions defined in `shell` scope. Only external tools (scripts) could be addressed by `xargs`!

Comment: **Warning!**  `eval` is evil! Don't use `eval` on user submited values! Never!

Comment: And "I want to use the same variable for logging and execution" is a poor reason to use `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

1. you don't need to use both the "function" keyword and the parentheses.
2. [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F050.I.27m_trying_to_put_a_command_in_a_variable.2C_but_the_complex_cases_always_fail.21)
3. [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Use an array to store the command, then you don't need to `eval`:

```
dc() {
    local command=( docker container "$@" )
    echo "${command[*]}"   # print it
    "${command[@]}"        # execute it
}
```

And to access your function via xargs:

```
dcp Image ID | xargs bash -XXX 'dc "$@"' _ ls
```

1. if you put the dc function in your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile, then -XXX is `-lc`
2. if you put the dc function in your ~/.bashrc, then -XXX is `-ic`
3. if you `export -f dc`, then -XXX is `-c`

ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files

---

your "Edit 1":

- is missing the required double quotes in the dcCall function (as demonstrated in my function above)
- the alias is defined with a double quoted string, so the shell variable *will be expanded when the alias is defined*.

Aliases are not the answer. If you want `dcp Repository ID | dc ls` behaviour, then

```
dc() {
    xargs docker container "$@"
}
```

---

Taking a bigger picture view, it seems the `dcp` function is specifically generating arguments for the `docker container ls` command, no? If yes, then I'd collapse that xargs pipeline into one function:

```
dls() {
    local OPTIND OPTARG
    local params=()

    while getopts ':p:' opt; do
        case $opt in
            p) params+=( "{{.$OPTARG}}"$'\t' ) ;;
            ?) echo "unknown option: -$OPTARG" >&2 ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND - 1))

    local docker_params=()
    if (( ${#params[@]} != 0)); then 
        docker_params+=( --format "table ${params[*]}" )
    fi

    echo docker container ls "${docker_params[@]}" "$@"
}
```

And you'd use it like

```
dls -p Image -p ID
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested, with a minor change. Now dc is declared as an alias, so that it can be easily piped, but now the arguments are not getting passed to dc. Updated code under Edit 1.